# Runtime display image from french drawable if language changed to french

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-drawable

I am developing an app with english and french language support.
If user change language , textview texts are changed.
But images in `ImageView` does not change.

If user selects language=='fr' image should be displayed from drawable-fr.

How to achieve this?

I am changing locale like:

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale(language);
// set the new locale
Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = myLocale;


getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
             getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: The answer is already inside the question... use **drawable-fr**. For reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Thanks . Please see edited question , is this correct way ?

Comment: You don't need to get the displayMetrics each time you change your locale. It's the DISPLAY metrics, not the LOCALE metrics, don't be fooled by the `metrics` word... Just add null to the `updateConfiguration(confifg, null);`

Comment: Ok. Bur=t still image does not changed in previous activity. 
i am changing image in onRestart()

Comment: When you change your locale, you have to reload everything that use the old locale. Finishing and restarting your activity will do the trick

Comment: Yes. this can work. But in my condition i have to call it from onRestart(). its not working with this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem.

As user changes language,i was resetting image like iv.setImageResouse(R.drawable.asdf); in onRestart() method of previous activity.

But then i replaced this with iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.asdf));

This worked.